# How to restrict the usage of GPU count for a user in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine, google-iam

For my use case, I need to create a user for the project for whom I have to limit the usage of GPU. E.g. If I give the GPU limit count as 2 for the user, then the user can add only 2 GPU to the VM in GCP.

I have tried to use the resource quota, but it seems like the limit offered by GCP is applied to the project.

I'm the admin and I have to restrict the usage of GPU for a particular user. It would be great if anyone can help in this!

Edit: Actually, its not about Quotas. I have sufficient GPUs in my project. I just want to put some restriction for the user to use only limited GPUs.

Comment: The quotas are per project, not per user. Or create a project per user!

Comment: Its not about quota. I'm trying to restrict the user by giving limited count of GPU to the users in GCP within the same project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user has the roles to create a Compute Engine instance and the project has GPU quota available they can attach GPUs. Google Cloud does not have constraints for GPUs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're right. But I'm the admin and I need to put constraint to the user for limited GPU usage. Is that possible?

Comment: @Jegan - Google Cloud does not have constraints for GPUs. Quota are per project. The only method is to reduce the GPU quota for the project. That will require you to contact Google. https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas